# MySQL, checking multiple dates between a range

Tags: mysql

I have three date columns in a db row. The columns are independent of each other in that any of them can either be populated or NULL.

I'd like to check to find all rows where any of the date columns fall within a known range.

This is what I have in my WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (d.date1 OR d.date2 OR d.date3) 
    BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46'
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't working would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you select where column A or column B have the value 2? "where (A or B) = 2" or "where A = 2 or B = 2"?

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding how logical "OR" works.

```
WHERE (d.date1 BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46') 
   OR (d.date2 BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46') 
   OR (d.date3 BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the three parts separately.

Note that `(d.date1 OR d.date2 OR d.date3)` will evaluate to `true` if any of the dates have a value, so your `WHERE` clause is currently the equivalent of this:

```
WHERE TRUE BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46'
```

So you'll need to test each date separately:

```
WHERE d.date1 BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46'
   OR d.date2 BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46'
   OR d.date3 BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46'
```

Comment: Great, thanks very much! This makes sense. However my the code I'm working with only allows me to use each of the known date variables once. So whilst the above is a logical outcome, I can't use it. I need some way of comparing each date against the range but only declaring the date range once. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing it like this:

```
WHERE (d.date1 BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46')
OR (d.date2 BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46')
OR (d.date3 BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Between operator needs a single value to the left of Between.  Reverse the sequence... like this:

```
WHERE d.date1 BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46' Or
      d.date2 BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46' Or
      d.date3 BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46'
```